# SSH tunnel to a google cloud VM from windows and putty : Network error : connection timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to my google cloud VM from a windows computer.

My normal machine is under linux and everything is ok on this one but right now, i can't use it so i try to connect from this windows' one.

I installed the gcloud sdk and when I try to open a ssh tunnel to connect to the web UI :

```
gcloud compute ssh my-spark-master --project=my-project --zone=us-east1-b -- -D localhost:10000 -N
```

i've got a Network error : connection timed out

The user is created on my VM (i have it in the home directory). I have a google_compute_engine.ppk on my local machine, 22 TCP port is open on my project. Ihave authorized "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe" in my windows firewall (but is it well done ?)

```
 gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22

To show all fields of the firewall, please show in JSON format: --format=json
To show all fields in table format, please see the examples in --help.
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **PuttyGen**, create up an SSH key (by randomly moving the mouse pointer and saving the PPK for later use) and add the text prefixed by `ssh-rsa *` into the Metadata -> SSH Keys in Compute Engine Service.

In PuttyGen, `Key-comment` mention a Username you want to use for logging in to your VM for e.g. **gcp-user**

Now when connecting to Google Cloud Compute Engine VM using **Putty**, just use that `gcp-user@<Public-IP-of-VM>` and in Key-pair use the above the saved PPK file.

Hope this helps you and let me know if any concern(s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer which made me test a simple ssh connection with putty. This is OK. I can connect to my VM with putty but I can't create any ssh tunnel which is needed to access web UI. The google command is "gcloud compute ssh my_vm --project=my_project --zone=us-east1-b -- -D localhost:10000 -N" and i also tried gcloud compute ssh user@my_vm --project=my_project --zone=us-east1-b -- -D localhost:10000 -N
with user = user i used for the normal putty connection

Comment: For SSH tunnelling, you've to do a lot of proxy related stuff within your web browser and then have to make ssh tunnel.

Comment: I finally managed to open an SSH tunnel directly from putty (not using the gcloud command). I the try to launch chrome with this command : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://my-vm:8123" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:10000" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXLUDE localhost" --user-data-dir=/tmp/my-vm which work under linux but it still doesn't connect correctly. Changing the whole system configuration isn't what i want as i still want to connect normally to the internet with other browsers...

Comment: To make it work there are certain tools like foxyproxy etc. but this is also fine.

Comment: But it doesn't work (with windows). I feel i am very near the solution but i can't find the problem. I'll give a try to foxyproxy when i have a minute (i'm back on a linux machine for this afternoon :-) )

Comment: With foxy proxy, it's OK. I can finally communicate through this tunnel. Thank you.